# Sort array object if two key's value number are equal then match to another key value pair

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, quicksort, ranking

I want to sort php object array in which i have to consider two different keys while sorting, if value of two users is same then consider another key for those values.

**given array example**

```
[{'id':'1','total_number':'90','previous_number':'75'},
 {'id':'2','total_number':'80','previous_number':'91'},
 {'id':'3','total_number':'80','previous_number':'84'},
 {'id':'4','total_number':'80','previous_number':'96'},
 {'id':'5','total_number':'95','previous_number':'80'}
]
```

**Result array:**

```
[{'id':'5','total_number':'95','previous_number':'80'}, 
 {'id':'1','total_number':'90','previous_number':'75'},
 {'id':'4','total_number':'80','previous_number':'96'},
 {'id':'2','total_number':'80','previous_number':'91'},
 {'id':'3','total_number':'80','previous_number':'84'} 
]
```

Comment: **modified result** if i have to add rank as well in same array so how can i add. if two user has same total_number then rank should be same as well.can you suggest some logic. or write set of code. –

`expected result -
[{'id':'5','total_number':'95','previous_number':'80,'rank':'1''}, 
 {'id':'1','total_number':'90','previous_number':'75','rank':'2'},
 {'id':'4','total_number':'80','previous_number':'96','rank':'3'},
 {'id':'2','total_number':'80','previous_number':'91','rank':'3'},
 {'id':'3','total_number':'80','previous_number':'84','rank':'3'} 
]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom sort function to achieve the desired result with the help of `usort` function in PHP https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

```
// custom sort function
function mySort($a, $b) {
  // is total_number same?
  if ($a->total_number === $b->total_number) {
    // use previous_number to sort
    if ($a->previous_number === $b->previous_number) {
      return 0;
    }
    // sort desc
    return $a->previous_number > $b->previous_number ? -1 : 1;
  }
  // sort desc
  return $a->total_number > $b->total_number ? -1 : 1;
}


// call the function
usort($array, 'mySort');
```

Comment: @gilan thanks for your answer.
if i have to add rank as well in same array so how can i add. 
if two user has same total_number then rank should be same as well.can you suggest some logic. or write set of code.

Comment: **modified result** if i have to add rank as well in same array so how can i add. if two user has same total_number then rank should be same as well.can you suggest some logic. or write set of code. – expected result - `[{'id':'5','total_number':'95','previous_number':'80,'rank':'1''}, {'id':'1','total_number':'90','previous_number':'75','rank':'2'}, {'id':'4','total_number':'80','previous_number':'96','rank':'3'}, {'id':'2','total_number':'80','previous_number':'91','rank':'3'}, {'id':'3','total_number':'80','previous_number':'84','rank':'3'} ]`